# Insert hyperlink if a cell is edited

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet, and whenever someone updates a cell, I want to use the   `onEdit(e)` function to perform two things:

1) Check if a cell has certain text, and
2) if it contains said text, add a hyperlink to said cell, with the same phrase/contents.

So if I enter "Yahoo" in cell A1, I want the cell to update to "Yahoo" with a hyperlink to whatever website I have in the script.

I'm not exactly sure where to go with this...

```
function onEdit(e){
// If the cell contains 'Yahoo", link it to the Google Search Results page for "Yahoo"
var cellval = e.value
if(cellval.match("Yahoo")!=null) value.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("//www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q="+"Yahoo", "Yahoo")')
 }
```

Something akin to this? I've tried to go off of the `onEdit(e)` simple trigger example as a basis (below), but something's not adding up:

```
function onEdit(e){
// Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
var range = e.range;
range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

Edit: I can get a cell to update once edited, but I want to have it specifically update *if* the cell contains certain text, not just based on the entire sheet.

Comment: So what is the problem right now?

Comment: Based on JPV's answer I can get a cell to update if it is edited within a certain sheet, but I want to narrow it down to update only if the cell contains certain text. I tried using `getActiveCell()`but I might be approaching it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Sheet1' || !e.value) return;
e.range.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("//www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=+' + e.value + '", "' + e.value + '")')
}
```

In the above example I 'limited' the script to only work on a sheet called 'Sheet1', as I can imagine you don't want this conversion everywhere ? If needed you can further limit it down to a certain column, or a certain range.

EDIT: only converting certain text (see var values)
In below script hyperlinks will only be created if any of the values in var values is entered (case-sensitive).

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var values = ['Google', 'Yahoo', 'Microsoft', 'Apple']
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Sheet1' || values.indexOf(e.value) == -1) return;
e.range.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("//www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=+' + e.value + '", "' + e.value + '")')
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly; I guess I'm trying to  figure out what I was missing.

Comment: I guess it boils down to using e.value (instead of the hardcoded 'yahoo'), getting the syntax of the formula right AND using e.range to get the edited range, where the formula needs to be set. Please accept my answer if it helped you out ?

Comment: The answer was correct in the sense that I understand how the cell updates if the sheet name is 'Sheet1' in your response, but I want it to check the cell contents for certain text and only update if the cell contains certain text, not just if the edited sheet is 'Sheet1'.

Comment: @PurposeUnknown: I don't think that was in the original question. However, it shouldn't be too difficult to change the script in such a direction. See my edited answer.

Comment: Managed to add my own parameters to make the update work, but interesting problem: when I then delete the cell, to add a new value, it updates with 'undefined'. I can still edit it with a new value, but I'm curious why it doesn't stay blank when I erase it.

Comment: I just tested the code I shared and it seems this code doesn't do that. If you want us to look at why that happens in your code, please share your code.